# Why isn't this cookie sent to other subdomains?

Tags: cookies, subdomain

We have an authentication API for signing in and a file download API that serves protected files.

The authentication API lives at `authentication.api.mysite.com` and returns the following header on a successful sign-in:

```
Set-Cookie: sessionId=QpiYzBXNNhiMZQSdWfKiDM; SameSite=None; Secure; HttpOnly; Domain=.mysite.com
```

(I have also tried `Domain=.mysite.com`, i.e. with a leading dot, without luck.)

The file API lives at `files.api.mysite.com` and allows clients to download protected files given the following request header:

```
Cookie: sessionId=QpiYzBXNNhiMZQSdWfKiDM
```

The APIs are used by a web app that lives at `something.othersite.com`. In the browser dev tools, I see that the sign-in response has the cookie in the "Cookies" tab, so I know it's set. And the cookie is sent to other requests against the authentication API. But no cookies are sent in requests to the file API.

As I understand it (e.g. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies)), if `Domain` is set to `mysite.com` (or `.mysite.com` judging by some other sources) then it should also be sent to `api.mysite.com` and `whatever.api.mysite.com`. But it's not sent to other subdomains.

What are we doing wrong? How can we get the browser to pass the cookie set by the authentication API on to the file API?

In case it's relevant: Both APIs use CORS, set up to allow the specific host we're using (not wildcard), allow any method, allow any header, allow credentials, and expose a set of headers I don't think is relevant (`Set-Cookie` isn't included there, but it made no difference when we added it).

Comment: I don't see anything from the header, does Chrome DevTools show anything against the cookie in the Network panel? i.e. if you select the request, go to the cookies tab, you should be able to see filtered out cookies and hover for why they were blocked.

It's also worth checking you don't have third-party cookie blocking enabled, either via incognito mode, your settings, or an extension. https://samesite-sandbox.glitch.me may help here.

Comment: Seems to have been some front-end code. It works now. I'll investigate and post an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cookie was correct; the problem was caused by how the front-end called the APIs. The front-end uses [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios#example), and the solution was to use the `withCredentials` option, e.g.:

```
axios.post(
  url,
  data, 
  { headers: headers,
    withCredentials: true }
)
```